# Change path to log shipping folder

Tags: sql-server-2008, log-shipping

We are moving our back-end storage so will need to change the paths for our log shipping. Can we do this without interrupting our log shipping? i.e. Just change the paths in the 'Network path to backup folder' field. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think you can, of course stop all jobs making sure that all logs have been applied (restored) on the secondary to make sure it stays in sync. It sounds like the jobs you will be changing are the backup job on the primary and the copy job on the secondary.

Comment: Thanks Rob. This worked, I disabled the backup job on the primary and the restore job on the secondary, I then edited the paths and re-enabled the jobs....all worked fine. Thanks again.